# Socket.io failed to load websocket.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io

I tried to use socket.io in an simple app.

When it is calling the following js file:

node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket.js

The following line failed to load (It didn't really fail. It actually returned some empty result and failed some later codes using protocolVersions):

```
var protocolVersions = require('./websocket');
```

I debugged a little bit and it seems that the intention of this line is to load the following js file:

node_modules\socket.io\lib\transports\websocket\index.js

However because there is also a "websocket.js" (the file being run) under the "transports" folder, the require functions always tries to load "websocket.js" instead, and return some unexpected results.

I changed the folder name to "websockets" and call "require('./websockets')" instead, and it fixed the problem. However this is a shared library I am not feeling comfortable messing up its codes.

I am trying to understand why this problem happened this way and what should be the best way to work around it. I am sure this piece of codes has been well tested before released.

You probably already noticed that I am using backslash '\' to separate the path. Yes I am running it on Windows! Will that create any difference?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you write your `app.js` in `node_modules/`?

Comment: The require for `socket.io@0.9.16` is for `./websocket/`, so with an added slash at the end.

Comment: To damphat: no my app is not in node_modules. All modules under "node_modules" are downloaded by npm.

Comment: To robertklep: I could just change the codes to work around it. But it is not really my codes. These are libraries automatically downloaded by npm, so I don't feel comfortable messing with it. It may create problem when it get deployed on a server. So I tried to understand why this problem happened. If this line has been tested, is it because the environment I am using is quite different?

Comment: I tried the same codes on OSX and it didn't have the same problem. I think it may be the environment different causing this failure and this version of socket.io probably was never tested on Windows.